# Is there a official way to install all Microsoft updates for Windows 8 offline without WSUS?

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

I am aware Microsoft publishes ISO images for security updates for a given month i.e. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40718 however the ISO image doesn't account for Windows 8.

Is there a way to get all the updates for Windows 8 without using WSUS or third-party applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [current ISO image](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41137) certainly does.

Note: Look in the Details section, not the system requirements one. This is true for your original October link as well. That specifies which KBs are for each system (many hit more than a single release).

Comment: Ah haste makes waste. My apologies.

Comment: Is there a similar ISO for other Microsoft products e.g. Office?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, nor in quick Google queries. But I would think that they can be procured for offline use.

Comment: What do you mean by "procured"?

Comment: You can probably search MS Technet for the updates, manually download them, and manually put them on media for offline use. Beyond that, I can't really say beyond I bet there's a way that I'm not currently seeing (on a mobile device).

Comment: - Hmmm, i was hoping for an easier way as opposed to a manual search and download

Comment: Probably appropriate for a new question, rather than tacking it on here. I'm sure someone knows a definitive yes/no and how.